# Electron.js how to invoke a function in preload.js and use in main.js

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a function in a file (`preferences.js`):

```
export const getFullPrefs = async function(id) {}
```

that I am trying to invoke in `preload.js` and use in `main.js`, but I can't figure out how to do it the right way. `preload` and `main` are in a folder that is a child folder of the folder that they share with the folder that `preferences` is in. I tried to do:

```
getPrefs: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('getPrefs')
```

in `preload` and in `main`:

```
ipcMain.handle('getPrefs', async (event, settings) => {
  window.getPrefs()
})
```

But nothing happens since its not getting used, but I dont know how to use it. Every other similar case, the function is called on the frontend js. Please let me know if this is not specific enough.

Comment: One thing is not very clear, is `getFullPrefs` a function only on your `preload`, or you also use it in your renderer files?

Comment: @Arkellys I do use it in the render files, but i would like to also use it in my main.js file. I feel like preload->main might not be the right way to go about it. But I cant find another way to call the function in main, which is my goal. Trying to import the function is not working

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a function of your `renderer` from `main`, then you can call your renderer directly using [`contents.send()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args). However, (if I understand your question correctly) it is currently not possible to wait for a renderer's reply as you would do the other way around with `invoke`/`handle`. So, if you want to get the result of the call, your `renderer` needs to send a message to `main` with the result.

For example:

**main.js**

```
// Assuming your window is stored in a const named `mainWindow`
mainWindow.webContents.send('getPrefs') // Sends a message to renderer to get prefs

ipcMain.on('getPrefs', (_event, result) => {
  // Gets the result of `getPrefs()`
})
```

**preload.js**

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  listenGetPrefs: (callback) => {
    ipcRenderer.on('getPrefs', (_event) => callback());
  }
  answerGetPrefs: (result) => {
    ipcRenderer.send('getPrefs', result);
  }
})
```

**renderer**

```
const getFullPrefs = async function(id) { /* ... */ }

const getPrefsAndAnswerMain = () => {
  const result = getFullPrefs();
  window.electronAPI.answerGetPrefs(result); // Send the result to main
}

// Listen when main wants to call `getPrefs()`
window.electronAPI.listenGetPrefs(getPrefsAndAnswerMain);
```

Comment: Is there a way I could do this where the renderer is two different files? The getFullPrefs is in a js file and it awaits an api call, but the window.electronAPI call is happening in the script of a vue screen?

Comment: @codingisforeboding You can import the functions in a file into another file. And all your renderer files can access what's exposed in your preload.